# App Store encryption compliance when using Hive for Flutter

Tags: flutter, encryption, app-store, app-store-connect, flutter-hive

When using Hive package for flutter, how should I answer the question regarding App Store encryption export compliance?

==============================================

According to [Hive's official package page](https://pub.dev/packages/hive), it uses AES-256 for encryption if used with that option.

If the provider of the encrypted functionality is a third party developer, how should I address the encryption export compliance for my app when it is time to publish it at the appstore?

This question was addressed in the project's github but there has not been any answer yet: https://github.com/isar/hive/issues/1113 citing this https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-app-information/overview-of-export-compliance

I've read about this in various stackoverflow questions but I'm kind of lost with this topic.

> I'm a junior-mid developer and this is my first project as a solo developer.